# In the change-of-variables theorem, must $\phi (A)$ be open?

Tags: integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

[image]

In the above theorem, is $\phi (A)$ necessarily an open set in $\mathbb R^n$ ?
The author (subsequently) suggests so, but I can't see why.

p.s. In the above, "a set has volume" is equivalent to "the boundary of the set has measure zero."

Comment: In that book, what sets can you integrate over?

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Presumably, the book defines integration of a function $f : U \to \mathbb{R}$ where $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Did that definition require $U$ to be open, or does it specify what integration meant for $U$ not open?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese The book's definition of integration merely requires that the domain of integration and the integrand both be bounded; the integral is the common value of the lower and upper integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\phi(A)$ is indeed open.

> *Proof*:
>   Since $J\phi(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in A$, by the inverse function theorem for every $x\in A$ we see that $x$ has an open neighborhood $U_x\subset A$ on which $\phi$ is one-to-one and onto, and the derivative of the inverse is defined and nonzero; that is, $\phi$ is a $C^1$ local diffeomorphism at all points of $A$. In particular, $\phi$ is an open mapping of $U)x$ into $\phi(A)$, i.e. $\phi(U_x)$ is open. Since
>   $$
> \phi(U) = \bigcup_{x\in U}\phi(U_x),
> $$
>   it follows that $\phi(U)$ is a union of open sets, and hence $\phi(U)$ is itself open.

This is purely topology and no analysis (other than the inverse function theorem), so if you're unfamiliar with point-set topology then this is probably slightly mystifying.

Comment: The part I don't get is why $\phi(U_x)$ should be open (I don't know what a local "diffeomorphism" is and the definition in terms of manifolds is a bit too advanced.) I do know that the image of an open set under a continuous injective function need not be open, so I'm somewhat surprised at this particular assertion.

Comment: Here (fortunately) we are dealing with subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, so there's no need to deal with manifolds. A homeomorphism is a one-to-one onto continuous map with continuous inverse. A diffeomorphism is a differentiable homeomorphism with differentiable inverse. An important theorem about mappings of Euclidean spaces of equal dimension is the invariance of domain: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain. This should be enough to convince you (up to actually proving invariance of domain, which requires some machinery).

Comment: Thanks, would you mind to take a look at a related follow-up question? http://math.stackexchange.com/q/623053/21813