# Show example that if $\phi$ is not injective then the change of variables might yield different result

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, change-of-variable

I need to find non-injective parameterization to some domain such that :
$$\int_D f(x,y) dxdy \ne \int_E (f\circ \phi)(u,v)J(u,v) dudv$$

The example I found turns out to be wrong. (The integral is the same when integrating using change of variables and direct computation).

**My try :**
The domain is $D=\{ 1\le xy \le 2 , 1 \le \frac {x}{y} \le 2\}$ and I want to calculate $\int_D 1dxdy$

The try is wrong, Thanks to @user1027216 comment.

I searched for a counter-example for hours in the internet and couldn't find one.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Two question: 1) can you explain how you obtain the bound limits in the first double integral? And 2) can you show the mapping $(u,v)\mapsto (uv,uv^{-1})$ is not injective? And it's $C^{1}$?

Comment: Well, the first part that you wrote with the double integral is not correct. Directly, it's more difficult the bound of integration of the region $D$.

Comment: It should be over $D$, $$\int_{1/2}^{1/\sqrt{2}}\int_{1/x}^{2x}\, {\rm d}y{\rm d}x+\int_{1/\sqrt{2}}^{1}\int_{x}^{2/x}{\rm d}y{\rm d}x=\frac{\ln 2}{2}.$$ The change of variables in the second part is injective and $C^{1}$. I'm not posting this as an answer, because this doesn't answer the question, it's just an observation/correction.

Comment: Yes , you are right , the integral in direct computation and change-variables results with the same answer.

Comment: Don't worry, by other hand I found a similar question here. Maybe it is useful? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/894716/1027216